# css- 2 different pages with div-tags

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, hyperlink

We're developing a web-app for the iPad with Rails and will let the data view with stylesheets from jQery Mobile. We divided into two teams, one team made the technical (Rails) part and the other the Graphical part.

So they already created an interface which looks like this:

[image]

The orange (`<div data-role="header">`) and the green (`<div data-role="content">`)part are both in two seperated div-containers, but actually they later should represent 2 different html.erbs: The orange one index.html.erb (/employee) which is linking to the green page show.html.erb (for example /employee/1)

Now my questions:

1. Is it possible to let 2 pages view with rails in one view? (With paginating?)
2. how to link from the orange to the green part so the lower part of the page will change, depending on which name you click? Is it possible to write something in the -containers?

---

Maybe it's hard to understand so I'll show some parts of our code.

```
<body> 

<!-- BEGINNING OF ORANGE PART: SEARCH BAR - index.html.erb -->
<div data-role="page" data-theme="d"> 

    <div data-role="header">
        <h6>Videobasiertes Lernsystem</h6>
        <p align="center">zur Sicherheit am Arbeitsplatz</p>

            <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">

            <h3>&nbsp;&nbsp;Mitarbeitersuche klappt aus</h3>

            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-theme="d">
                <br></br>

                <li><p><a href="TO THE GREEN PART">Anne Wernersen</a></p></li>
                <li><p><a href="TO THE GREEN PART">Klaus Meyer</a></p></li>
                <li><p><a href="TO THE GREEN PART">Thomas Sach</a></p></li>

            </ul>
        </div><!-- /Ende Suche -->

    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">


<!-- BEGINNING OF GREEN PART: CONTENT - show.html.erb -->
    <!-- left panel -->
    <div class="ui-grid-b">
        <div class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a"><p><strong>Faehigkeiten</Strong></p>
            ...

            ...
    </div></div></div>

<!-- /End of left panel -->

<!-- right panel -->


        <div class="ui-block-b"><strong><p>Schulungen</p></strong>

            <br></br>
            <br></br>
        ...

        ...

        </div></div></div><!-- /right panel -->

    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="d">
    </div><!-- /footer -->
    </div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

---

and I thought about that maybe I need to write in the `divs` something like `<%= render 'index' %>` and write the real code in both other html. Like it's for example with the edit.html.erb and _form.html.erb in the scaffolding of rails.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use jQuery to do this for you. The Rails view will load all the data and you use JavaScript to control how the page changes when people interact with it.

If it is a ton of data and depending on other factors, you might want to set up an API to your data so that your JavaScript can request the data of each person from there.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your point. Can you give me some simple example so I can understand?